# How to hide the floating cell toolbar in Jupyterlab?

Tags: jupyter-lab

I am used to the keyboard shortcuts and I don't like the cell toolbar.

I did my best to search but I still can't find how. If someone knows please let me know.

[image: cell toolbar]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Straight from [the documentation](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/notebook.html#notebooks):

> If you would like to disable the cell toolbar, run `jupyter labextension disable @jupyterlab/cell-toolbar-extension` on the command line. You can enable it again by running `jupyter labextension enable @jupyterlab/cell-toolbar-extension`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I should have looked into the documentation more carefully first, not elsewhere.