# How to remove the control shortcuts from active cell in Jupyter Lab?

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

I updated Jupyter Lab recently and it shows me this little control shortcuts on the active cell which i find annoying.

How can it be removed?

[image]

I tried to find an option under View but couldnt find a relevant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings -> Advanced Settings Editor -> Cell Toolbar -> Check the "Whether the item is ignored or not" in each toolbar items

Comment: This does not disable the cell toolbar itself, which will still be rendered and potentially cause issues for screen readers (and impose a performance penalty for no reason). JupyterLab documentation provides instructions for disabling the cell toolbar altogether as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73659405/how-to-hide-the-floating-cell-toolbar-in-jupyterlab/73660171#73660171