# How to show play button in every code cell for jupyter lab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

In vscode and colab, there's a play button in every code cell in the notebook. [This issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54607200/remove-play-button-display-at-every-cell-line-of-jupyter-notebook) seems to suggest there should be the play button in `notebook` 5.6.0, but I'm on 5.6.1 (and using jupyterlab), there's no play button along the cells.

Same issue seem to suggest css can be used to control the display of the button. Is that the only way? Would be good if there's a configuration somewhere, considering it should be a common element, and both vscode and colab has it by default.

Comment: JupyterLab, which is the modern offering of the Jupyter Project has it. To see, go [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/requirements#python-environment-with-a-requirementstxt) and click on 'launch binder'. You'll get a temporary session on a remote machine. (Currently, if you use the 'Try Jupyter' site and request JupyterLab, you get JupyterLite and while that has the same interface and so shows the cell toolbar, JupyterLite has some sharp edges that make it have some unexpected hurdles.) [This thread](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3772) linked from where you link ...

Comment: <continued> suggests it was disabled by default unless on a mobile device. Down towards the bottom [there](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3772#issuecomment-435856463) is discussion of how enable it everywhere, I think. I haven't tested it. I would, however, caution that how the current classic notebook interface works won't be the norm much longer because as described [here](https://jupyter.org/enhancement-proposals/79-notebook-v7/notebook-v7.html) the next document-centric version of what is the current classic interface will be built off JupyterLab components. And thus a lot ...

Comment: <continued> of the ways enabling special things in the classic notebook interface will be much different in the version to be coming out soon.

Comment: sorry, it is jupyterlab in the question. I thought [that link](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3772) suggest it's enabled by default for desktop, and asking how to remove it?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that the title clearly said JupyterLab. What version are you using? And when you say desktop, there's also a Jupyter Desktop that doesn't run in the browser, see [here](https://blog.jupyter.org/jupyterlab-desktop-2022-recap-28bdf00205c6). Is yours in the browser or not? I think by default it is enabled in the current typical installs. And so you know ['That link'](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3772) you point to though is not about JupyterLab and probably part of my confusion. That's about the classic Jupyter Notebook interface.

Comment: The JupyterLab repo with JupyterLab issues is at  https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab, not https://github.com/jupyter/notebook , which where that issue you pointed at in your last comment was. This shows one place to look into the settings for the controller bar in JupyterLAb: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75406942/8508004).

Answer (score 0):

I found this plugin useful to add play button.

> pip install jupyterlab_play_cell_button

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).